# angular 2 extend select when hovered

Tags: angular, angular-material

We have a form with many mat-selects (basically drop downs). We use these so we do not have to do painful validations since users cannot input junk. They can only select a valid value. Now users are complaining that they have to scroll thru so many items to find the right one. We want to improve this by showing only those options that they most likely/normally 90% of time use and show additional options only if they hover over the last option called "show more" or something like that. I have a basic skeleton setup on stackblitz. Appreciate any pointers/working code. Totally stuck. This is nothing to do with lazy loading. Just visual trickery.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showmo

Comment: Why not a simple autocomplete from a predefined list? (you can always order the list based on most clicked elements)

Comment: Maybe you could use material [autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) instead of selects

Comment: @GCSDC, that link is awesome. Material autocomplete is the best and does it for me. Thanks

Comment: although you have decided to go with autocomplete, please see my answer below to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you need it to do.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showmo-nftpk7?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.html

Add disabled boolean to interface

```
export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
  disabled: boolean;
}
```

define default food array

```
foods: Food[] = [
    { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak', disabled: false },
    { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza', disabled: false },
    { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos', disabled: false },
    { value: 'showSpecials', viewValue: 'Show Specials', disabled: true },
  ];
```

`addSpecials(food)` method to append new values if `food.value == 'showSpecials'`.

```
 addSpecials(food) {
    if (food.value == 'showSpecials') {
      this.foods.push(
        { value: 'pizza-special-1', viewValue: 'PizzaSpecial', disabled: false },
        { value: 'tacos-2-special-2', viewValue: 'TacosSpecials', disabled: false }
      )
    }
  }
```

html to disable specials option and call `addSpecials()` on mouse enter.

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" [disabled]="food.disabled" (mouseenter)="addSpecials(food)">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some thoughts, this is merely a pseudo code, just to illustarte..
I'd split the list of options into frequent and rest. Then have three different `mat-option` tags under the `mat-select`.

First will show the frequent items, second will be the hover option `show more` and the third will be the rest of the options.

Use a hover event on the `show more` `mat-option` to enable the second set of `mat-option`:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foodsFrequent" [value]="food.value">
                              {{food.viewValue}}
                            </mat-option>
                            <mat-option *ngIf("showMore == false") (hover) = "setTrueShowMore">Show more</mat-option>
                            <mat-option *ngIf("showMore") *ngFor="let food of foodsRest" [value]="food.value">
                                {{food.viewValue}}
                              </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Will try this. Will wait for day or two for ideas from others.

Answer (score 0):

This goes against the reasoning you would use a select box in the first place - the user should know what value they want for the most part, and doesn't need to know or see all the alternatives.

Users should be able to type a few letters bringing them to the option or option area that they want to use.

If you really want to do it as a 'show more' implementation, I would suggest switching to Radio buttons instead, as those can easily by hidden/shown by a clickable link or button, and are also useful in the case that a user needs to see all the possible options and make a decision.

If your list is too long for this, you could do 2 select boxes, one being hidden and with a show more button to display it.

Comment: Regarding >Users should be able to type a few letters. < Most of our drop downs have numeric values. I will test how typing works. This may do the trick as well. Thanks

Comment: Typing in the select should also work for numeric values, though I'm interested why not use a text input for it if its numeric? Unless of course there are other non-numeric values as well. You can limit the text input to only accept numbers, and can then ensure the numbers are within a certain range pretty easily checking the value in your JS.